# Extract documents from EXE file

Tags: pdf, extract

My school provide us with a free training software which includes all the stuff we need for study but the problem is that it comes in EXE format so i was thinking is there any way to extract the output files like PDF's compressed inside without running the EXE through Wine as it crashes on start and useless for me in this case.

Comment: If you right click on the *.exe file do you get the **Extract Here** option on the drop down menu?

Comment: using the **Extract Here** i get "An error occurred while loading the archive"

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract/). It works with many exe files.

Comment: I think I'll download this, it looks good... or not, it appears to be for windows only :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by installing the software using Wine without running it then browsed in the Wine directory where application files are stored and i found all the Documents i wanted, just copied them and ready to use.

Comment: How do you install it without running it?